# How can I access the arguments that were provided to a function that I've stubbed in Sinon?

Tags: ember.js, stub, sinon

I'm trying to test an EmberJS app that uses `Ember.run.debounce`. I'd like to use Sinon to stub `Ember.run.debounce` so that it will just call the debounced method synchronously. Something like this:

```
debounceStub = sinon.stub(Ember.run, 'debounce')
debounceStub.callsArgWith(1, debounceStub.args[0][2])
```

to make this code run synchronously:

```
Ember.run.debounce(@, @handleData, list, 500)
```

but `handleData()` is being called with an undefined argument rather than `list`. Any help figuring out how to pass `list` in the `callsArgWith` call would be greatly appreciated.

Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason `handleData` is called with undefined is because the point at which you're defining the behaviour of the stub (`callsWithArg(...)`) is before the stub has been invoked (through executing your unit-under-test), so the reference to the args is not available yet.

It's a bit ugly, but one solution is to manually invoke the method passed to `debounce`, something like...

```
debounceStub = sinon.stub(Ember.run, 'debounce')

//...execute unit-under-test so that `debounce` is called...

//Then pull out the arguments from the call
var callArgs = debounceStub.firstCall.args.slice();
var targetObject = callArgs.shift();
var methodToCall = callArgs.shift();
var methodArgsToPass = callArgs.shift();

//Manually invoke the method passed to `debounce`.
methodToCall.apply(targetObject, methodArgsToPass);

//perform your assertions...
```